# How to decorate a GTK window like eg. the gnome-panel?

Tags: python, gtk, panel, window-decoration

I would like to make a panel-like application, in appearance much like the gnome-panel. I would like to use GTK for this (although i've looked into Qt), preferably using Python.

How can i decorate the window in such a way a color/gradient/bitmap/svg is applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use styles (the example below uses inline style strings):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

pixmap_rc = """
pixmap_path "/home/foo/images"
style "bar" {
    bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "logo.svg"
} widget "*foo" style "bar"
"""

color_rc= """
style "bar" {
    bg[NORMAL] = "Hot Pink"
} widget "*foo" style "bar"
"""

def main ():
    window = gtk.Window()
    window.set_decorated(False)
    window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

    window.set_name("foo")
    gtk.rc_parse_string(color_rc)

    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main ()
```

Setting color gradient via gtkrc seems to be engine-specific, though.

**Edit:** here goes minimalistic gtkrc example with stretched background image:

```
pixmap_path "/home/foo/images"
style "bar" {
    engine "pixmap" {
        image {
            function = FLAT_BOX
            file     = "test.png"
            stretch  = TRUE
        }
    }
} widget "*foo" style "bar"
```

Comment: Nice one, thank! :) Do you have any suggestion of documentation or tutorial on styles?

Comment: @Benjamin: check this one for a start: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes

Comment: @barti_ddu the documentation on gnome.org is very succint. Something i don't understand: styles in the code overrides styles of the Gnome WM theme? Can i also use an already existing style? For instance i want to use the gnome-panel.rc file and use that style? How do i apply that style to my application? One last thing: can i specify _stretch_ or _tile_ for pixmaps? The current example is tiling the pixmap. Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin: styles in the example are nothing special, they are ordinary gtkrc styles that obey all normal rules, i.e. may be inherited, extended, etc. I've embedded them as inline strings, but you could save them as external file and load it with `gtk.rc_parse(filename)` instead. And yes, you could stretch the background image, however afair this can not be done with plain gtk, you should utilize engine for that (e.g. "pixmap"), have a look at http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkEngines/PixmapEngine (especially FLAT_BOX function). And, imho, we are getting out of scope there :)

Comment: @Benjamin: see edit for bg image stretching using pixmap engine

Comment: @barti_ddu: great stuff, thanks! One last question: why is the style using this funny code rather than regular Python code? It looks like CSS, am i correct?

Comment: @Benjamin: arghh, wrong pep :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Multi-line_string_literals

Comment: I also add [this Q&A on GTK](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq08.013.htp) which answers the question with a nice example.